# Email notifications for when events align with location. How?

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, notifications

I am looking at building a webapp in php/mysql that people can log into, and sign up to receive email notifications when a certain event is at their chosen location, e.g a jack johnson concert in new zealand, receivng a notification when he comes to that location to perform. I am guessing that there is some online concert database that apps like shazam use that i could intergrate with. 
Any help on building this sort of app would be appreciated, most importantly the notification system and how that integrates with another concert database and the users details .
I have a basic knowledge of php/mysql, I'm guessing I should use a framewok for this, if anyone knows one useful for this task that would be appreciated too.
Thankyou!

Comment: Your question is very open ended. See what kind of questions you can ask here - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Bro i just want someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Always check [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com) when looking fr APIs. I found the [Gruvr API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/gruvr):

> Gruvr offers tons of geocoded concert data, with about 170K upcoming
>   shows for 45K bands currently listed. You can ask for upcoming
>   concerts by location or by band. The results can be returned as
>   geoRSS, KML, or dynamic map links.

For triggering events, checkout [momentapp](http://momentapp.com/), which lets you schedule delayed HTTP requests.

Maybe you could start from there. What you could do is when somebody signs up with their location, check Gruvr if there are any upcoming concerts in their area, then schedule a request with momentapp which will trigger your email notification script at a specified time before the event to alert the user.

You can also use [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) as an alternative to using a 3rd-party service like momentapp.

I think your question can be broken down into more questions.

Comment: Hey thanks man. Thats exactly what i needed. Im new here sorry if my question could have of been asked differently. Thanks though.